# GET SESSION value in database.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am created a project in codeigniter but the project has multiple DBS. It works well but I am looking to call one DB dependant on the users table details

in the database.php file I wish to load the session username to query

I have done the following

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

if(!empty($this->session->userdata('username')))
$username_c = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't do that in `database.php` file if we are talking of `APPPATH . 'config/database.php'` but in part of code where is respective database set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tpojka said in comment, you shouldn't do it in `database.php`. You can choose database dynamically and get instance before query from it. Check [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html).

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "db_one";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['second_db']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['second_db']['username'] = "root";
$db['second_db']['password'] = "";
$db['second_db']['database'] = "db_two";
$db['second_db']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['second_db']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['second_db']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['second_db']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['second_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['second_db']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['second_db']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['second_db']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['second_db']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['second_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['second_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In your model,

```
public function get_profile() {
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata('username'))) {
        $username_c = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $DB2 = $this->load->database('second_db', TRUE); // true to get db instance
        return $DB2->select("*")->from("user")->get()->row(); // query from second DB
    }

    $this->db->select("*")->from("user")->get()->row(); // query from default DB
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.